# VlcControl.TakeSnapshot produces a file but is empty

Tags: c#, libvlc

My VlcControl in winforms does not take snapshots when invoked. The file is created, but when I open the file, it cannot be opened and the bytes is 0. I don't get any errors. Please see my code below:

```
private void CaptureImage(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var outputFile = $@"{imageDirectory}/{fileName}.jpg";
                vlcControl1.TakeSnapshot(new FileInfo(outputFile), 400, 400);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            
        }
```

This are the files created:

[image]

I can stream without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to take a snapshot on another thread or try to take a snapshot without specifying the size of the snapshot.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => vlcControl1.TakeSnapshot(new FileInfo(outputFile), 400, 400));
```

Comment: Am sorry Sir, I should have posted the filepath of the image as well not just the variables. The issue was the way the filepath was formatted. It should have been "D:\\FolderName/SubFolder/FileName.jpg"